# Mysql charset for displaying hebrew with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, character-encoding

Since I was unable to find a solution over stack-overflow and on the net I am posting this question:

I have a php page that contains the following:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-language" CONTENT="he">
```

and a php function that gets Hebrew chars and displays it on the above php page. 
The mySql DB is defined as utf-general-ci. Also the PDO connection is set as follow:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",   $username, $password);
```

The problem is that the php page displayed html Hebrew chars but regarding the DB Hebrew values - it displays them as question marks inside a triangle...

Any body got any idea what is wrong...? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `ISO-8859-8` charset to display the chars and `utf8` to encode them in your database, **you need to use one of them but not both** (I recommand you unicode/utf-8).

**EDIT :** Also, be careful with your file encoding.

Comment: Thank,  Should I only display the chars or only encode them?

Comment: I can see that the Hebrew values from DB are display correctly in the page, but the html Hebrew chars are not... only if I replace the meta tag to be: ISO-8859-8. So if I do that, then the Hebrew values from DB are showing "?????"... can't find the reason for that.

Comment: Check the encoding of your HTML file, it needs to be the same as your meta tag and DB encoding

Comment: Yes I know but like I wrote above, When the meta tag is set to utf-8 I see the DB Hebrew values fine, but not the Hebrew chars in the page. When I switch the meta to ISO-8859-8, I get the opposite: DB values are "???" and Hebrew chars are from page are fine...

Comment: Switch everything to either ISO-8859-8 or UTF-8 and you'll be fine.